# csrutil is broken on Recovery HD

Tags: recovery, macos

I'm trying to turn off SIP on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) but when I run OS X in Recovery Mode no `csrutil` is available—there is no such command in `/usr/bin` as well. So I tried to run it from `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/bin` where I have installed OS X. Good news is that `csrutil` is there. Bad news is it's crashing:

http://pastebin.com/qXVAdkaK

```
dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSDictionary0__
    Referenced from: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/bin/./csrutil
    Expected in:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
in /Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/bin/./csrutil
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Why would need to turn it off if your using 10.9.3?  Have you updated to El Capitan where SIP is used.

Comment: I don't know why that signature shows up - I'm using el capitan. 
Maybe it's some autodetect script from apple.stackexchange.com? I don't know.

Comment: There are no autodetect scripts to insert signatures on AD

Comment: It was added on apple discussions forum first and I just copied body from there. And there is auto signature with your machine specified in account settings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution - I just restored Recovery Partition locally on disk using script Recovery Partition Creator (which is working for 10.11 without any problems) - http://musings.silvertooth.us/2013/10/recovery-partition-creator-3-7-updated-for-mavericks/

Now when I reboot to recovery mode I can turn off SIP just by typing `csrutil disable` in Terminal.

So in general - to get this working you **need** to have Recovery Partition **locally** on disk.

Comment: I was so pumped when I saw this but alas the script said my version of OS X isn't support :( 10.11.3

Comment: It doesn't matter - for my OS X version it also said it's not supported but works anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

The `crsutil` tool runs on 10.11 and not 10.10 or earlier.

You'd need to fully install 10.11 El Capitan on a USB drive and boot to that Recovery HD for the proper libraries to be present. When recovery is on a different raw disk than the volume, I suspect you won't get the changes you desire.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "You'd need to fully install 10.11 El Capitan on a USB drive" are your referring to creating a USB Installer for OS X 10.11 or actually installing to the USB Drive as if installing to e.g. Macintosh HD?  I'm assuming you mean the latter however just want clarity on it.

Comment: @user3439894 Great question - I was vague. The latter. Both the recovery HD and the associated OS need to match for the linkage between the two to work in my testing. Most of my testing is pre-release, so this _could_ have changed in the last version/public X.0 build.

Comment: I don't know why that signature shows up - I'm using el capitan. Maybe it's some autodetect script from apple.stackexchange.com? I don't know.

Comment: Also I don't have Recovery HD locally on disk. When I type CMD + R the recovery loads itself from Apple servers.

Comment: Your above comment is probably the culprit.  Try running it with a local recovery partition.  Like the USB method bmike pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Honestly I don't get it. How booting Recovery HD on USB installed El Capitan would resolve in running command on my local disk with my local installation of El Capitan?